# How to find the first term and ratio from this geometric series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, polynomials

I have a question about geometric series.  Here's the question:

> Given a geometric series with the sums of the three first terms is $\frac{3}{64}$ and the fourth term is $\frac{1}{8}$ .
>   Find the possible value of its first term and its ratio?

My attempts:

I think I need to use the fact that $S_n - S_{n-1} = U_n$ and also the formula for the partial sum of the geometric series 
$$ S_n = \frac{a(r^n-1)}{r-1}$$

I applied it to get

$$S_4 - S_3 = U_4$$

$$S_4 = \frac{11}{64}$$

Then, I apply the $S_n$ formula for geometric series such that:

$$\frac{a(r^3-1)}{r-1} = \frac{3}{64}$$
$$\frac{a}{r-1} = \frac{3}{64(r^3-1)}$$

$$\frac{a(r^4-1)}{r-1} = \frac{11}{64}$$

Substitute the same term at S3 to the S4 such that :

$$\frac{3(r^4-1)}{64(r^3-1)} = \frac{11}{64}$$

Then, I try to use algebra and get:

$$(r+1)(3r^2-27r-22)-11=0$$

But, I check wolfram and only get the unfriendly anwsers and also the complex solution, which I don't desire.

Can somebody help me to find another way to tackle this problem?  Thanks

Comment: The desired solutions needs a real solution, not a complex solution.  Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You  have
$$u_1=a \qquad u_2=ar \qquad u_3=ar^2 \qquad u_4=ar^3 $$ So, what is given is
$$u_1+u_2+u_3=a(1+r+r^2)=\frac 3 {64}\tag 1$$ $$u_4=a r^3=\frac 1 {8}\tag 2$$ Frm $(1)$ $$a=\frac{3}{64 \left(r^2+r+1\right)}\tag 3$$ Plug in $(2)$ to get
$$\frac{3r^3}{64 \left(r^2+r+1\right)}=\frac 18\tag 4$$ which write $$3r^3-8r^2-8r-8=0 \tag 5$$ which is not exactly what you obtained.

So, you need to solve for $r$ the cubic equation. If you use Cardano method, you will notice, from the discriminant, that there is one real root and two complex root. Using Cardano formula, the real root is given by
$$r=\frac{1}{9} \left(8+\sqrt[3]{2348-108 \sqrt{257}}+ \sqrt[3]{2348+108
   \sqrt{257}}\right)\approx3.60998$$ Use this result in $(2)$ and get $a\approx 0.00265702$.

Let us check

$$u_1\approx 0.00265702\qquad u_2\approx 0.00959179\qquad u_3\approx 0.0346262\qquad u_4=\frac 18$$ $$u_1+u_2+u_3=0.046875=\frac 3 {64}$$

**Edit**

If you want to look fancy, using what is given [here](https://wikivisually.com/wiki/Cubic_equation#Hyperbolic_solution_for_one_real_root), you could write
$$r=\frac{8}{9}+\frac{4\sqrt{34}}{9}  \cosh \left(\frac{1}{3} \cosh
   ^{-1}\left(\frac{587}{68 \sqrt{34}}\right)\right)\qquad \text{and}\qquad a=\frac 1{8r^3}$$

Comment: What is Cardano methods? So, in this problem, we can only get the 'unfriendly' solution?  Thanks anyway

Comment: @akusaja. For solving cubic equations. As you wrote, if no typo, just *'unfriendly' solution* !

Comment: is it possible if  we use another way like vieta's formula?  Thanks